# Regular Expression to get text between words separated with line break

Tags: regex, vbscript

I need to get the text between two words but both the words are in different line using regular expression in vb script.

For Example,

> Hello World
>  Information Address 908 BLVD
>  Avenue Property Type
>   Occupied

I need "908 BLVD Avenue" using regex.So my regex pattern must be anything between "Address" and "Property Type". Till now , I could able to find "908 BLVD" using (?<=Address)(.*)\s but unable to get text before Property Type in same regex function.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following example code `[\s\S]+` means we're looking for matches with all whitespaces and all non-whitespaces, which simply means **everything**. It's required to match with line breaks in VBScript's RegeExp.

The next `?` in the pattern on the other hand means that we're not looking a greedy match, so it stops at the first `Property Type` encountered. Otherwise, the regex engine will continue to scan until the end of the text to find other matches unnecessarily.

```vb
str = "Hello World" & vbNewLine & _ 
"Information Address 908 BLVD" & vbNewLine & _
"Avenue Property Type Occupied"

Set ReAddress = New RegExp
ReAddress.Pattern = "Address ([\s\S]+?) Property Type"
Set matches = ReAddress.Execute(str)
If matches.Count > 0 Then
    'print first group of first match
    WScript.Echo matches.Item(0).Submatches(0)
Else
    'no matches found
End If
```

Expected output:

```
908 BLVD
Avenue
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! https://stackoverflow.com/users/893670/kul-tigin.  I didn't assumed it in this way . Thanks again.